# How to prevent JQuery change event from triggering when select's HTML is changed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

I have a select element that has a change event attached so that, when the user selects a new option, that text is placed into a corresponding input element. That's working fine:

```
$("select[name='" + dropdown_name + "']").live("change", function()
{
    text = $("select[name='" + dropdown_name + "'] option:selected").text();
    $("#" + inputfield).val(text);
});
```

However, when another select is changed, that select field's html is changed according to an AJAX request. When this happens, the selected value from the select element pre-HTML change is placed into the input field.

```
$.get("file.php", {x: x, y: y}, function(text)
{
$("select[name='dropdown_name']").html(text).removeAttr("disabled");
    if (!$("select[name='dropdown_name'] option.selected").length)
    {
        $("select[name='dropdown_name'] option[value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
    }
    $("#_inputfield").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

How do I prevent that particular function from occurring *only* when the HTML is changed?

Answer (score 2):

1) remove binding;

2) make changes;

3) restore binding.

Or use some checked value (maybe, value of hidden input) - to reduce event binding changes.

Comment: A had a similar problem and this was the best solution for it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could log that the change was in the ajax control and access that in your change event..

```
(function(){
  var changedByAjax;
  $(document).on('change', 
                 "select[name='" + dropdown_name + "']", 
                 function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    // make sure the change wasn't by ajax
    if( !changedByAjax ) { 
      text = $select.find("option:selected").text();
      $("#" + inputfield).val(text);
    }
    changedByAjax = false; 
  });

  $.get("file.php", {x: x, y: y}, function(text) {
    var $select = $("select[name='dropdown_name']")
    $select.html(text).removeProp("disabled"); 

    // make note that we changed the value by ajax
    if ( !$select.find("option.selected").length ) {
      $select.find("option[value='1']").prop("selected", true);
    }
    $("#_inputfield").removeProp("disabled");
  });
}());
```

I added `changedByAjax` into your ajax call and checked for it in your *change* event (Also reset the value in the changed event). This is less overhead than unbinding and rebinding. Kept it private by putting it in an IIFE - the power of scope. However, this is way too DOM centric of an approach. But, alas, an answer.